# 530U4C Power Connecter component peeled off from the board

Tags: laptop, motherboard, laptop-repair

I have a 530u4c laptop while unplugging the power connector cable i peeled off the connector legs of the component from the board and the motherboard does not get power right now.

Is it possible to repair this?

[image]

Comment: If it's fixable depends on your soldering skills.

Comment: See https://www.instructables.com/id/Repairing-a-Damaged-Pad-on-a-PCB/ . Removing the solder mask (colored lacquer) without damaging copper traces is important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are those are just mechanical fixing lugs. It's the pads on the actual pins that you need to check for damage.

If the other pads are fine then you could simply use a cyanoacrylate glue (a.k.a. superglue) to fix it back in place.

Comment: I checked the actual pins, they seem fine. Only the legs are peeled off.

Comment: It seems you are right. the technician said the legs are just for support. He said there is something wrong with the underlying circuit not the component.